# Excel table too big for VBA code - simplify code?

Tags: vba, excel, 32bit-64bit

I have an Excel table with 37 rows and 8000 columns. The table is not intuitive in that an observation is found in a column, rather than a row. As you can see, the structure is like this:  Category (Title) - Entry - Category (Author)- Entry etc. etc.. Eventually, I want a nice cleaned up data-set which has categories in row 1 and observations in the remaining rows.

[image]

The first problem I had is that not all observations include all categories: Columns 1-5 do not contain "Funding" (F12 category name, F13 content). Now I managed to compile my very first VBA code with the help of @Xabier, which inserts two blank cells and shifts the rest below if for instance row 12 does not contain "Funding". I have done this for all category lines.I have tried the code on fewer observations and it seemed to be working. 
[image]

This is the code:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
'declare and set your Sheet above
'lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'find the last row with data on Column A

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(2, i).Value = "Title" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(2, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(2, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(4, i).Value = "Author" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(4, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(4, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(6, i).Value = "Unit" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(6, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(6, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(8, i).Value = "Keyword" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(8, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(8, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(10, i).Value = "Abstract" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(10, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(10, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(12, i).Value = "Funding" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(12, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(12, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(14, i).Value = "Source" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(14, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(14, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(16, i).Value = "Date" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(16, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(16, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(18, i).Value = "Page" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(18, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(18, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(20, i).Value = "ISSN" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(20, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(20, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(22, i).Value = "CN" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(22, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(22, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(24, i).Value = "Language" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(24, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(24, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(26, i).Value = "ClassificationNumber" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(26, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(26, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(28, i).Value = "DOI" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(28, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(28, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(30, i).Value = "TimesCited" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(30, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(30, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(32, i).Value = "Citesothers" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(32, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(32, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(34, i).Value = "CitedReferences" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(34, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(34, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 8000 'loop from column 1 to last
    If Not ws.Cells(36, i).Value = "Citedby" Then 'if category is not found,
        ws.Cells(36, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
        ws.Cells(36, i).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

However, with the bigger dataset, Excel eventually crashes, after running a while. While I have a Windows 10 64 Bit version, I only have Excel with 32 bit, as I need to work with my university's computer. Now I suspect that it might have something to do with that. However, the university does not want to reinstall the programm as 64 bit version. 
Is there anyway in which I can fix my problem through making the code easier, or breaking it up into pieces? I am very inexperienced, so I am not sure whether and if so how that would even work.
Any help appreciated!

Edit: Trying to get it done with arrays:

```
Sub dd()
Dim firstRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

firstRow = 1
lastRow = 37

Dim tableArray() As Variant
Dim k As Long

With dataWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

tableArray = .Range(.Cells(firstRow, 1), _
                            .Cells(lastRow, 8000)).Value

For k = 1 To 8000 'for each column in the table

If tableArray(4, k) = "Author" Then
Else
    ws.Cells(4, k).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
    ws.Cells(4, k).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i

End If

If tableArray(6, k) = "Keyword" Then
Else
    ws.Cells(6, k).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell in column i
    ws.Cells(6, k).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell in column i

End If

Dim worksheetRange As Range
Set worksheetRange = .Range(.Cells(firstRow, 1), _
                            .Cells(lastRow, 8000))
worksheetRange.Value = tableArray

End With

End Sub
```

Edit: Loading my data into an array

```
 Sub dynamicMultidimensionalArray()
    Dim Chinese() As Variant
    Dim Dimension1 As Long, dimension2 As Long

    Dimension1 = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    dimension2 = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    ReDim Chinese(0 To Dimension1, 0 To dimension2)




    For Dimension1 = LBound(Chinese, 1) To UBound(Chinese, 1)
        For dimension2 = LBound(Chinese, 2) To UBound(Chinese, 2)
            Chinese(Dimension1, dimension2) = Range("A1").Offset(Dimension1, dimension2).Value
        Next dimension2
    Next Dimension1
```

Comment: I'm using also a 32-Bit system and I have recognized: even windows is giving the error, that excel is not responding, it will finish eventually (but that might be just in my case). If you want to avoid Excel crashing, split the code into several subprocedures. Call them manually or interrupt the execution between every code with a MsgBox.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look closely at your code, but you seem to be checking a `cell.value` and are iterating over `8000` columns. A rule of thumb regarding this is iterating directly through cells in a worksheet via vba is extremely slow and inefficient. You must first load your data into array like this:

```
Dim firstRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

firstRow = 1
lastRow = 37

Dim tableArray() As Variant
Dim k As Long

With dataWorkbook.Worksheets("YOUR_SHEET_NAME")

tableArray = .Range(.Cells(firstRow, 1), _
                            .Cells(lastRow, 8000)).value
```

Then you do all the iterating within vba: over array:

```
For k = 1 To 8000 'for each column in the table

If tableArray(4, k) = "Author" Then
   ...
Else
   'edit the existing array: tableArray, not a worksheet!
End If

Next
```

Then after you're finished with editing the `tableArray` and have its final version you can load it into worksheet in one go:

```
Dim worksheetRange As Range
Set worksheetRange = .Range(.Cells(firstRow, 1), _
                            .Cells(lastRow, 8000))
worksheetRange.value = tableArray

End With
```

If you have any questions feel free to ask. I've been dealing with big tables for a while myself, so I know the pain.

Comment: thanks for your help, this is much appreciated. As I justed started with VBA, I haven't yet come across arrays. I do understand the logic behind calling individual arrays, however, I don't get it to work. I have now written with two if-else statements what you suggested and added the code to my original post. However, I get the error "End with without with" when running it. I wonder whether the code is actually meant to appear in the same module? Or one after the other, and if so how do I do this?

Comment: @SCW You just need to put a `End With` statement before sub ends.

Comment: Hi, @Ans, I still get the same error in the same line if I add an additional "End with" in the second-to-last line, i.e. it complains that there is an "End with" that does not have a "with".  There is however a "With " command in line 7, no? I assumed that the "with...end with" command would work like brackets? Thanks!

Comment: @SCW Could you send me your file with code? Or wait, you say there's extra `end with`, so just delete the extra one.

Comment: @SCW I took a look at your edit with array code. It looks there's something a bit off about that also - you see, you say in code `With dataWorkbook...` and then use `ws.Cells`. I suggest googling a couple of `With` examples. It's quite simple - when you put `With 'something'` you no longer need to use `'something'.Cells` syntax. My code was just an example with different names, for example you seem to have named your workbook as `ws`, while I named it `dataWorkbook`. If that is so, after `With ws` you just use `.Cells` and vba would understand you mean cells inside `ws` workbook.

Comment: Hello @Ans. I understand with...end with now, and I understand the idea of an array. I also managed to load my data into an array (see my edit) . But then I don't know what to do with my array called "Chinese". I was that stuck that I now have written a new code 8 times (for Column 1-1000, 1001-2000 etc). Not elegant, and takes time, but at least it works :/